How do you write out proofs in set theory?
Can you write them out in the same you would in FoL? For example I have this problem: Show that if A is a set and A ∈ B, then A ⊆ ⋃︁B.
Could I prove it like this?

Let A = {x: x ∈ A}

Let B = {A,...}

⋃︁B = {x : x belongs to an element of B}, i.e., = {x : there is a A ∈ B so that x ∈ A}

Therefore, ⋃︁B = {x}

A ⊆ ⋃︁B ⟺ ∀x(x ∈ A ⊃ x ∈ ⋃︁B)

Therefore A ⊆ ⋃︁B


Does this work? As I was writing this I felt like I should have been writing (from 3 and 4) for example as justifications but it feels a lot more step-by-step than a regular proof in FoL so it felt redundant.
Just wondering if this looks okay or if I'm not getting the right formatting, or if it could be tightened up a bit.
Edit: I've noticed premise 1 is better written out as just 'let x ∈ A'.

OP: Is everything a set, or are there ur-elements?

@BrianTung Doesn't matter.

@ArturoMagidin: No, but I'm curious. ¶ In response to your earlier comment, I had thought that expression not quite kosher, but I suppose if it's universally understood, it's not an abuse of notation!

@BrianTung I don't think so.

Writing
$$A = \{x\mid x\in A\}$$
is... bad. Bad. Very bad. You are essentially saying "$A$ is the set of all things that are in $A$." To which I might ask: so... is $x$ an element of $A$, and your answer would be "Well, $x$ is and element of $A$ if and only if $x$ is an element of $A$." Which... does not really say anything.
Line 3 has a serious problem, too. The set $A$ is a fixed, given set. But in line 3 you are using $A$ as a variable. In your line $3$, the formula
$$\{x\mid \text{there is a }A\in B\text{ so that }x\in A\}$$
says "the set of all $x$ for which there exists some set in $B$, which for the purposes of this sentence and this sentence only I will call $A$, with the property that $x$ is an element of $A$."
The $A$ in that formula has nothing to do with the $A$ in line 1. It is just a name given to a random set for the purposes of the statement within the curly brackets in 3, and nothing more.
Your claim that $\cup B =\{x\}$ is not correct. Note that in "set builder notation", $\{x\mid P(x)\}$ is shorthand for "all $x$ for which $P(x)$ is true". There, $x$ is a variable. So in your line 3, $x$ is a variable.
But $\{x\}$ is shorthand "for the set whose only element is  $x$." Here, $x$ is not a variable, it is supposed to be a specific set which has already been identified and named.
So I would say that this (i) has a lot of bad notation, and in some places incoherent notation; and (ii) contains errors: Line 4 is just plain wrong, and line 6 is unjustified.
Line 5 is correct; that's just the definition of $A\subseteq \cup B$. That's the only one, I would say.
You should start with Line 5, as that is the statement of what you want to prove.
Then you can continue with "Let $x\in A$. We want to prove that $x\in\cup B$.
That means finding an element $y\in B$ such that $x\in y$.
Then you can state that we know that $A\in B$.
So $x\in A$ and $A\in B$.
So $x\in \cup B$.
Therefore, for every $x$, $x\in A\implies x\in \cup B$.
so $A\subseteq \cup B$.
